# "wore at" vs "wore out"

Tags: idioms, phrase-meaning

Is the use of "wore at" vs "wore out" the same?

Few Google examples:

*"She was tired of apologizing for the intractability of the land, its people, for the distances that **wore at** him, the endless driving."*

*"He said he still enjoys training and competing, but living on the road **wore at** him more as he got older."*

*"The thought of never seeing his mother and father again **wore at** him."*

Comment: Two different meanings.  "Wore at him" means "irritated him" or "taxed him".  "Wore him out" means "left him exhausted".

Comment: @Hot Licks, if you can provide any reference (e.g., dictionaries) I think you should make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, *wear at* (or *on*) is incremental and *wear out* is total.  Something is worn *out* when wear has made it useless; this may or may not be the result of something wearing *at* it over a long time.

Comment: Please find "wear at" in a dictionary.

Comment: And "wear on". They may be there, but not with the meanings you give them.

Comment: My dictionaries are in boxes, so I'm reduced to relying on what I hear people say.

Answer (score 0):

"To wear at" doesn't exist. At least, in BrE [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wore%20at%20him%2C%20wear%20at%20him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) has no examples of "wear at him" or "wore at him" and in [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wore%20at%20him%2Cwear%20at%20him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwore%20at%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwear%20at%20him%3B%2Cc0) there are very few examples: probably all mistakes.

You can wear something, you can wear it down, wear it out, wear it away...

**Dictionaries are your friends!**

Comment: Try "on": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wore+on+me%2C+wore+on+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwore%20on%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwore%20on%20him%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @ Hot Licks That's a search for "wore on", not "wore at".

Comment: That's what I said, "on".

Comment: Yes. "Wore on him" sounds better to me. But if you click on "1896 - 2005" below that graph to go to Google Books, there are only two actual examples of its use.

Comment: It seems perfectly cromulent to me.

Answer (score 0):

Contra Old Brixtonian, BrE and AmE both use "to wear at", e.g. BrE: [Cambridge English Dictionary: **wear**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wear): to become weaker, damaged, or thinner because of continuous use: *I really like this shirt but it's starting to wear at the collar.* ; AmE: [MacMillan Dictionary: **wear**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/wear_1): if something wears or wears thin, it gets thinner or weaker because it has been used a lot: *His shoes were wearing at the heel.*

Comment: I think these examples are not the same as those given in the question (the former refer to clothes, the latter to toleration of people/events)

Comment: What you're actually seeing is the difference between intransitive and transitive usage, literal and metaphorical usage, the clothes being (passive-voice) worn-at or worn-down in the sense of weakened by abrasion, the distances and road-living (active-voice) wearing-at or wearing-down those men, again weakening them by metaphorical abrasion of their spirits.

Comment: Old Brixtonian's AmE link is to Google Books, which brings up examples like [St. Charles Church history](https://parish.stcharleshartland.com/page/mission_statement_and_history) "Yet after years of struggling, Charles’s tireless work began to **wear at** him. In 1584 he became ill with a fever and died." ; [CJ Cherryh, _The Pride of Chanur_](https://books.google.com/books?id=JdVJAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT178&dq=%22wear+at+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF6-_6_ITjAhWTW80KHaj7ACUQuwUILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22wear%20at%20him%22&f=false) "This go-and-stop-again psyching for challenge would wear at him by the hour."

Comment: Likewise see ['wore at me' examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wore%20at%20me%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), e.g.: (KR Schulteis, _Calling_) "The pressure **wore at me**." ; (Steven Gould, _Exo_) "But I was getting cold and the roar of the wind **wore at me**." ; (Bridget Boland, _The Doula_) "That way of meeting life's challenges **wore at me**,...."

Comment: Things become worn. (Damaged and shabby as a result of much use). Clothes might become worn at the elbows or at the cuffs or around the neck. Nothing wears at people. Please find me that usage in a dictionary. Of course we know what the writer _means_: the same as we know what he/she means by "bob wire fence". And there seem to be more or less as many books containing "bob wire fence" as there are containing "wore at me". Perhaps "bob wire" will make it into the dictionaries if people say it enough. But I hope "wear at" _doesn't_. It's not as funny.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian : "_Things_ become worn. ... _Clothes_ might become worn.... Nothing wears at _people_." -- You've looked at the adjective applied to objects, but not at [Cambridge English Dictionary - "**worn**"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worn) _adjective_ (PERSON) very tired, and seeming old : _The period of bad health had left her looking tired and **worn**._

Comment: @Raven If the original question had asked about "the distances left him looking worn", "living on the road meant he was feeling worn" and "the thought made him worn" then that would be OK. It is the words "wore at him" that I'm questioning. There are many examples of the usage of your "tired" meaning at https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/wear but not one of them has the formula "X wears _at_". If it existed I think it would _be_ there.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian “_ wore at him” [in books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wore+at+him%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks), and [elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=-site%3Astackexchange.com+%22wore-at-him%22). Examples include “exhaustion wore at him”; “maladies wore at him” [obit]: “the job wore at him”; “the injustices of the world wore at him”; “the cares that wore at him”; “living on the road wore at him more as he got older”; “the persistent attention wore at him”; “his conscience wore at him”; … all suggesting attrition of physical or emotional strength and endurance.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian This is of course consistent with “wear at” objects, e.g. (of a sawhorse) [“Rain and snow and pounding light wore at it.”](https://billstclair.com/gloryroad/sawhorse.html).

Comment: See also ["wear away at"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wear+away+at)